# Using assert-payload option in munit in mule

Tags: mule, munit

I'm getting xml file as output while running munit test case for the flow, but to make sure the output is correct or not i want to use assert payload option in munit.

Please help me how can i make sure the code functionality is working properly and the output is as expected.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting XML payload either you can compare entire XML output with test resource file as `#[getResource('output.xml').asString()]` or you can use XPath expression to check specific fields in output XML.

HTH.

Comment: one pof my field is having timestamp,How can we assert that.When i convert to string the file will be having old timestamp